# "Table des Matières" instead of "Table of Contents"

Tags: babel

Currently, I write a report in LaTeX. 
Everything goes well except a small problem that bothers me really. The report is written in English except for a summary in French that has to be written in French, for this reason I have imported the `\usepackage[french, english]{babel}`.

By creating the table of Contents with the command `\tableofcontents`, the generated document shows *Table des Matières* instead of *Table of Contents*. It translated the phrase into French!

The packages I used:

```
\documentclass[english]{report}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[colorlinks,breaklinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{afterpage} %
\usepackage{microtype} % makes pdf look better
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 10):

Just after `\begin{document}` put `\selectlanguage{english}`; then switch back to French just before the French part of the text: `\selectlanguage{french}`.

Answer (score 6):

See this description of the [babel](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Internationalization#Hyphenating) package.

Just after `\begin{document}` switch to english with

```
\selectlanguage{english}
```

This will create a *Table of Contents*, not a *Table des Matières*.

Then, just before your summary in french, add

```
\selectlanguage{french}
```

And just after it, switch back to english

```
\selectlanguage{english}
```